# Counting occurences in a column within SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, count

This is what I have at the moment in terms of data:

| Customer_id | Choco_type |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | Milk |
| 544 | Dark |
| 74 | White |
| 100 | White |
| 544 | Milk |
| 82 | Crisp |
| 544 | White |
| 544 | White |

What I am looking to achieve is to find out for example is this:

| Customer_id | Choco_type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Milk | 2 |
| 544 | Dark | 1 |
| 74 | White | 1 |
| 544 | Milk | 1 |
| 82 | Crisp | 1 |
| 544 | White | 2 |

Comment: 'Hopefully this makes sense.' - not a lot, what should your output look like? Also supply sample data as text.

Comment: is the table you have a screenshot of (which should be text) your source data or the result you are looking to achieve?

Comment: Please share the source tables and example data that would be use to generate your expected result.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement (as text we can copy/paste, not images); the `INSERT` statements (again, as text) for your sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** attempt; and the expected output (again as text, not images). If you only tell us the expected output then we have to guess at the input and you will only get an appropriate solution if we guess correctly.

Comment: @ConfusedJJ PLease pass the  original table as well...

Comment: I recently updated the request. Could i possibly have this re-opened? Many thanks

Comment: Why does 100/Milk have a count of 2? In the original data there is one 100/Milk and one 100/White. Also, APC's answer appears to solve your problem [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9114211b0827b142ed0dbbfe32756515).

Comment: @ConfusedJJ - have you looked at my answer? Does that not solve your problem? If it doesn't please explain what additional clarification you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use GROUP BY to aggregate data. In this case you want a count, so...

```
select  id
       ,chocolate_type
       ,count(*)
from your_table
group by id
        ,chocolate_type
/
```

If you just want to know how many different types of chocolate each person has bought you would do this:

```
select  id
       ,count(distinct chocolate_type)
from your_table
group by id
/
```

---

You haven't posted your table structure, so I have made some assumptions. You will need to adjust my code examples to fit your actual situation.